# Loading rgdal library on shinyapps.io fails

Tags: r, shiny, rgdal, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy an R shiny webapp to their hosted services shinyapps. This app works with geojson data in the form of spatial polygons. The app does work fine locally. When I deploy it, everything works wonderful till the moment the browser openes.

To the point: The logs tell me, the app is unable to locate a shared object in the rgdal library. The Error code is below.

```
Fehler in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  kann shared object '/opt/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so' nicht laden:
  /opt/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10OGRFeature11SetGeometryEP11OGRGeometry
```

I have already tried the hints given at RStudio. I also tried to upload a backup of the app which I fetched before uploading my new code. Afterwards, I upgraded all my packages, restarted the computer, reinstalled RStudio in a new environment, the error is still persistant.

If I leave the geojson data out, the app fetches all the other data as expected and works exactly as intended. Using other packages probably not work either as most of them depend on rgdal.

Do you have any idea how to tackle this?

Thank you.

Edit: I am working with R 3.5.1 and all the latest versions of packages.

Comment: "Using other packages probably not work either as most of them depend on rgdal" - what are you using to read the geojson, and which other libraries are you loading?

Comment: I'm using the readOGR function from rgdal itself. The other packages I am using are: 1) shiny 2) leaflet 3) tidyverse 4)countrycode 5) Quandl 6) comtradr. You're right, the other functions regarding spatial polygons won't work either. I can, however, read the geojson data w/o using the sp / rgdal package.

Comment: try with `sf::st_read()` or `geojsonsf::geojson_sf()`

Comment: Hello again,

please excuse my late reply.

I tried your approaches and the geojsonf - one worked. 

I noticed it's easier to use the worldmap of the package "maps" as it provides basic polygons.

Thanks for your help!